# Visual Styles not working (C# VS2010)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem with Visual Styles on my WinForm app (.net framework 2) and I fail to find any solution googling for a long time.

The forms in this project look styled in IDE (as should be), but in runtime they appear to be with no styles applied in any OS.

I've tried:

1) Put in my program.cs

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.DoEvents();
```

before the form creation and that doesn't help

2) Insert *System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();* in form constructor.

2) delete, create new manifest that doesn't help either.

After some debugging I found that *VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser* is returning FALSE instead of True as it should be. I have very similar application using the same resources and libraries which works absolutely fine, with all styles applied and it is returning TRUE for IsEnabledByUser.

Does anybody have any ideas how to nail it?

Answer (score 0):

Next to all the actions you took, you should also make sure that the FlatStyle property of your controls is set to `FlatStyle.System`. Check if this true for all your controls, including your Form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I've checked this property for all controls and all controls had FlatStyle property as Standard. It looks like the form doesn't have such property.  I've changed this property to System for all elements having it and that doesn't help.  
I've checked my other project that has no problem with FlatStyle and it has Standard for all control's FlatStyle property.

Comment: I searched about FlatStyle. And it appears that starting .NET Framework 2.0 it is not necessary to set FlatStyle to System in order to apply Visual Styles. But worth a try. Any other ideas please?